# Jquery ui dialog autoclose with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to close my ui message dialog automatically after 3 sec.
I tried in this way but I don't know why it doesn't work. (dialog isn't self closing)

```
$("#success").dialog( "open" ).html( html_msg );
$("#success").on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) { window.location = url } )
```

with button action (works perfectly)

```
$("#success").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  dialogClass: 'success',
  buttons: {
    'Close': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        }
     }
});
```

with autoclose (not works)

```
$('#success').dialog({
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  show: "blind",
  hide: "blind",
  modal: true,
  dialogClass: 'success',
  open: function(event, ui) {
     setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).dialog('close');                
         }, 3000);
    }

});
```

where am I wrong? Which is the correct method to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use the **ID** instead of using `this` here:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#success').dialog('close');                
    }, 3000);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr7Ws/)